# Change css property using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Please check the code bellow. I want to change a css property after click on 'switch' button. Whats wrong i am doing here? Also please help me to do this with any other way if possible. Thanks all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


<button id="myButton">switch</button>

<p class="foo">Some text</p>




<script type="text/javascript">

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").attr("background", "red");
});

</script>


<style>
.foo {
  background: gray;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `.css` method instad of `.attr`

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

please change `attr` to `css` in jquery.

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">switch</button>
<p class="foo">Some text</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When changing css properties, use the `$.css()` method:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
  // Or, for multiple properties:
  $(this).css({
    "background": "blue",
    "color": "white",
    "border": "2px solid yellow",
    "font-weight": "bold"
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myButton">switch</button>
<p class="foo">Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`css()`** method for this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
});
```

Refer to [***this w3schools***](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) link for more info.

**Here is working sample with your work file.**

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <button id="myButton">switch</button>

  <p class="foo">Some text</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Background isn't tag attribute, it's css property. It means you should try this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("background", "red");
});
```